# How to Detect database data changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, checksum

In Sql Server database, is there a way to detect data changes, i tried to do that using `checksum` & `checksum_agg` but on a **single table**,  all i want is to have the entire checksum (hash) for all tables

the query i used for a signle table is

```
select isnull(CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(*)),0) from mytable
```

Comment: If you need reliable difference detection, don't use `CHECKSUM` alone. As you surely know it is impossible to reduce an entire database to a unique 32 bit value.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers.

I'm not sure that this will be efficient.  As the table grows the computation will become more costly.  Are you sure you need to do this every time data changes?  How often are changes made?  You're throwing a lot of work away with every operation.  Maybe you can do it on request when needed rather than with every write operation.

Comment: no all I need is a query that check the sum of the entire data (then using that *Int* in my code to do other tasks)

Comment: But you have to recalculate that sum every time.  What does a checksum tell you?  I see no meaningful use case here.

Comment: Checksum tells that **at least one cell have been changed in the database**, because in my code "C#" i do updates for my listviews, ... and other tasks

Comment: There are many better ways to determine whether at least one value (not *cell*) has been changed in the database.

Comment: such as ???? @Catcall, but don't forget that i need to retrieve that value via a query into my c# code

Comment: You never said anything about retrieving changed values until just now. How do you expect a database-level checksum (the sole requirement in your original question) to help with that new requirement?

Comment: I think i made my question clear enough, i need a database-level checksum nothing more, because @duffymo asked me **What does a checksum tell you? **

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'SP_MSFOREACHTABLE' command to run a loop through all of your tables and aggregate the sums

Comment: i've used the following query `CREATE TABLE  #tempchecksum (chksm int)
 
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'Insert into #tempchecksum select isnull(CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(*)),0) as hs from ?'

 SELECT checksum_agg(chksm) from #tempchecksum
 
DROP TABLE  #tempchecksum`, does this has any effects on memory

Comment: You don't really need to worry about memory here, SQL Server has automated execution plans for temporary tables.  Larger temp tables are automatically moved out of memory and into the 'tempdb' system database

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)) as test FROM yor_table_name WITH (NOLOCK);
```

You can detect the change in sql server with this code, there is a number pool here and a number is selected for each change, a number does not come twice in a row.